# Does Wake-on-Lan in Windows 10 work without the Wake-on-LAN utility?

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

Every article I find online about WoL says to first enable WoL on the computer, then go get the WoL utility at Sourceforge.

But, if WoL is so built in to Windows that enabling it is built right into the Power Management window for network adapters, one might reasonably suspect that actually using the feature is also built into Windows.

Like many, I want to be able access a network share (locally, not remotely) even if the machine it's on has fallen asleep.  Can I do it without a 3rd party utility?

(Crossing my fingers the correct answer is that locally Windows Explorer will always be able to see the network share, and just selecting it will awaken the machine.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wake-up on LAN (WoL) is first and foremost a firmware (BIOS or UEFI) feature. If not present then the OS can't wake-up on its own.

The Ethernet port must be kept "alive" (ON) even if the rest of the machine is not (OFF) in order to receive the wake-up packet.